# How to map a new keyboard shortcut for 'Hide all other windows'?

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, imac

I know and I like using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to hide all other windows but I find it a little long of a shortcut, where can I map it to something shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change shortcuts in the keyboard preference pane:

[image]